# How to bind nested json configuration to options in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In .net core if we have to bind the configuration directly from Json configuration as shown below

```
{  
  "AzureAdJwtSettings": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid",
  },
  "WebSecJwtSettings": {
    "Authority": "https://example.com",
  }
}
```

we can write something like this

```
configuration.Bind("AzureAdJwtSettings", options);
```

I am looking to find a way so that I can group my json configuration in such a way

```
{  
  "JwtSettings": {
    "AzureAdJwtSettings": {
      "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid"
    },
    "WebSecJwtSettings": {
      "Authority": "https://example.com"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try to load the configuration in my code it didn't load properly.. I am using the below code

```
configuration.Bind("JwtSettings.AzureAdJwtSettings", options);
```

I know there must be way to load nested properties but couldn't find it working...

Comment: Use colon (`:`) instead of dot (`.`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per suggested comments, the format should use colon (`:`) instead of dot (`.`) with keys for configuration option binding to work

For example

```
configuration.Bind("JwtSettings:AzureAdJwtSettings", options);
```